# Windows cmd prompt/powershell command with an OR in the `find`?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell

I come from a BSD/GNU/Linux command line experience.
For example
`ps aux | grep 'USER\|http'`
that prints out the header containing the word "USER" OR any lines containing "http".
(The backlash escaped pipe symbol or vertical bar does the OR part -- the "|")

Is there an equivalent with the `find` command in Windows?

For example, Windows 10 command prompt:
Get a list of listening port lines that have the number 443 in them:

`netstat -aonp TCP | find "443"`

I want to OR it up by including the header line that has the word Proto as the first column (  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID)

I know I can't use a backslash since that doesn't have the same meaning in Windows.  Don't know the Windows equivalent of the "|" to mean OR.

Is it something like `... find "443" -o "Proto"` for either Cmd or Powershell?

Comment: There are grep versions for Windows so you could continue to use the way you know. I am mostly a Windows user but I also prefer grep and some other *nix command-line tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** try:
`command | findstr "string1[SPACE]string2"`

```bath
netstat -aonp TCP | findstr "443 proto"
```

---

For **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)** try:
`(command | Out_String) |  Select-String '(string1,string2)'`

```bath
(netstat -aonp TCP | Out-String ) | sls '(proto|433)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use PowerShell and combine `netstat` with `Select-String`

```
netstat -aonp TCP | Select-String -Pattern "443","Proto" -NoEmphasis
```

Comment: 'M. Behresn.' Your command is specific to PowerShell Core. Still a good pointer for folks that are there. Especially for those running PS on *NIX, since PS Core is the only option there. I added mine just in case the OP was not there yet. Especially, since the OP mentioned DOS/CMD.exe options.

Comment: Remove "-NoEmphasis" and it's valid for PowerShell 5.1

Answer (score 1):

You can also use RegEx match to 'OR' things up.

```
(netstat -aonp TCP) -match 'proto|135|443'
```

In DOS/CMD.exe, it's a bit more cumbersome, and you'd lean toward 'FINDSTR' instead of just 'FIND'. For example:

```
netstat -aonp TCP | findstr /i /c:"proto" /c:"135" /c:"443"

# Create your own object to manipulate
Clear-Host
(((netstat -aonp TCP | 
Select-Object -Skip 3).trim()) -replace '\s\s+', ',')  | 
ConvertFrom-Csv | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
Proto Local Address     Foreign Address    State       PID  
----- -------------     ---------------    -----       ---  
TCP   0.0.0.0:7         0.0.0.0:0          LISTENING   6892 
TCP   0.0.0.0:9         0.0.0.0:0          LISTENING   6892 
TCP   0.0.0.0:13        0.0.0.0:0          LISTENING   6892
...
#>

Clear-Host
(((netstat -aonp TCP | 
Select-Object -Skip 3).trim()) -replace '\s\s+', ',')  | 
ConvertFrom-Csv | 
Select-Object -Property '*' | 
Where-Object {$PSitem.'Foreign Address' -match '135|443'} | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
Proto Local Address    Foreign Address    State        PID  
----- -------------    ---------------    -----        ---  
TCP   10.0.0.xxx:5xxx   xx.xx.240.xxx:443  ESTABLISHED 5716 
TCP   10.0.0.xxx:5xxx  xxx.xx.163.xxx:443  CLOSE_WAIT  19916
TCP   10.0.0.xxx:5xxx  xxx.xx.163.xxx:443  CLOSE_WAIT  19916
...
#>
```

Just an FYI as others or pointing to

> All PS. [See also:](https://adamtheautomator.com/netstat-port/#:%7E:text=%20On%20your%20Windows%20PC%3A%20%201%20Open,see%20PowerShell%20returns%20a%20lot%20more...%20More%20)

```
Get-NetTCPConnection | 
Where-Object {$PSitem.RemotePort -match '445|443'}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer to the question you asked, but in general on (non-ancient) Windows a lot of things you do on Unix in text form can instead by done in PowerShell with properly typed data, more like SQL or JSON than shell. For this case:

- instead of running a program (netstat) to get info about TCP connections (or more exactly socket endpoints) you can use the 'cmdlet' get-nettcpconnection
- instead of searching text output for a substring, you can filter *values*. I assume you used `-a` because you want to include sockets in listen state and really want to find the process(es?) using *local port* 443 not remote. Adding `-localport 443` does this filtering -- and does NOT include sockets which use port 4437 or 14430 or 22443 or have *pid* 4430 or *remote* port 443 or 4439, which you text search will include but you don't actually want. OTOH if you actually wanted remote port 443 (which doesn't really make sense with `-a`) do `-remoteport 443`.
- by default the nettcpconnection structure doesn't display the owning process but that can be overridden with format-table, which automatically supplies the  header lines, and additional information about a process can be obtained by a different cmdlet get-process

As a worked example I don't have anything on 443, but do have a virtualbox listening on 7022:

```
PS C:\work> get-nettcpconnection -localport 7022  |format-table localaddress,localport,owningprocess

localaddress localport owningprocess
------------ --------- -------------
0.0.0.0           7022         12132

PS C:\work> get-process -id 12132

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
   1093      63   124696      91768      43.00  12132   1 VirtualBoxVM
```

You could customize the info about the process, and even combine these into a single pipeline which gets the socket info PLUS the process info, but I'd need more exact requirements.